# How to solve StackOverflowException after upgrading from AutoMapper 8 to 11.0.0

Tags: automapper, blazor-server-side

https://github.com/beolafsen/TestAutomapperAndStripe

I get this errors after upgrade AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection from 8.1.1 to 11.0.0.

The messages I get are:
*"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll."*
(No other hint where or what causes the error).

and

[image]

I use .Net 6.0/BlazorServerSide

I have found that the following Automapper definitions are causing the error.

```
using Stripe;
    CreateMap<VMStripeInvoiceItem, Stripe.InvoiceItem>();
    CreateMap<Stripe.InvoiceItem, VMStripeInvoiceItem>()
                    .ForMember(pts => pts.LineAmount, opt => opt.MapFrom(ps => ps.Quantity * (ps.UnitAmountDecimal ?? (decimal)0) * (decimal)0.01))
                    .ForMember(pts => pts.UnitAmountDecimal, opt => opt.MapFrom(ps => (ps.UnitAmountDecimal ?? (decimal)0) * (decimal)0.01));

public class VMStripeInvoiceItem : InvoiceItem
    {
        public decimal LineAmount { get; set; }
    }
```

How can this be solved?

Thanks for helping!

Best regards
BEO

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: You will find example code here: https://github.com/beolafsen/TestAutomapperAndStripe

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: Tried to install from MyGet but got this error: Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 11.0.1-alpha.0.6 -Source https://www.myget.org/F/automapperdev/api/v3/index.json - Install-Package : NU1102: Unable to find package AutoMapper with version (>= 11.0.1-alpha.0.6) - - Found 218 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 11.0.0 ]

Comment: MyGet seems down, try again later :)